# Query is correct, but getting 'undefined' data

Tags: graphql, axios, apollo, react-apollo

Sup guys.
I'm learning Apollo GraphQL with React, and i just made a project consuming and open API (only using GET)
Facing my final problem before i can deploy my application: "undefined" data when i try to GET using an ID (Int).

**Github Repo:** https://github.com/akzeitions/reactbeer

My Query (works at GraphiQL):

```js
const CERVEJA_QUERY = gql`
 query CervejaQuery($id: Int!){
    cerveja(id : $id){
        id
       name
       tagline
       image_url
       abv
       ibu
     }
}
`;
```

`console.log(CERVEJA_QUERY);`

[image]

Probably the problem: Resolve

```js
const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields:{ 
     cerveja: {
      type: new GraphQLList(CervejaType),
            args: {
                id : {type : GraphQLInt}
            },
            resolve(parent, args) {
              return axios
                .get(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${args.id}`)
                .then(res => res.data);
            }
          },
```

```js
export class CervejaDetalhe extends Component {
  render() {

    //get and parse ID
    let { id } = this.props.match.params;
    id = parseInt(id);

    return (
    <Fragment>
        <Query query={CERVEJA_QUERY} variables={{ id }}>
        {
          ({ loading, error, data  }) => {
                if (loading) return <h4>Carregando...</h4>
                if (error) console.log(error)



                const {
                    name,
                    tagline,
                    image_url,
                    abv,
                    ibu
                } = data;

                //undefined :(

                return (
                <div>
                    <h1 className="display-4 my-3">
                    Cerveja : {name}
                    </h1>
                </div>
```

Just lost some hours reading, making tests and trying to figure out without success. :(

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: @marktani https://github.com/akzeitions/reactbeer , thank you.

Comment: Please edit your question with exactly the code that is relevant.

Comment: @marktani sry, edited with the class :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be in your server implementation.

Your type `ceveja` is returning a list `type: new GraphQLList(CervejaType)` but you are expecting to get only one record instead of a List.

Also, the api `api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${args.id}` returns an array (`List`) so you should transform it into a object as well.

You should change your `RootQuery` into something like:

```
  const RootQuery = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields:{ 
     cerveja: {
      type: CervejaType, // HERE: remove the List
      args: {
        id : {type : GraphQLInt}
      },
      resolve(parent, args) {
        return axios
              .get(`https://api.punkapi.com/v2/beers/${args.id}`)
              .then(res => {
                // HERE: you need to transform the data from the API into
                // one object instead of an array
                const [data] = res.data
                return data
              });
        }
     },
```

Comment: i used a different approach, but that helped, thank you.